# DateTime ToString without using the genitive month name

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to output a `DateTime` like this `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")` But when I've set a culture like `cs-CZ` I don't want the genitive month name in this output. Is it possible to say that to the `ToString()` function?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy") \\ returns "14 března 2016"
```

And I would like to get:

```
"14 březen 2016"
```

I need this because I have to parse this `DateTime` to a jquery datepicker and that can't handle genitive names.

Comment: Can you posn an example of the output which would be satisfying?

Comment: you need month name in localized language ?

Comment: @Anand yes, I've it locolized but I don't need the genitive version.

Comment: @SonerGönül yes you're right and that my whole problem I don't want to display the genitive version.

Comment: Well, is it *correct* without the genitive month name in Czech? If it's linguistically *incorrect* and you use the formatted date for data transfer to another component (the date picker), you are likely doing something wrong (that is, in addition, prone to break on systems with other language settings).

Answer (score 1):

Okey. I digg this with .NET Team and here what we get as a result.

Tarek Mahmoud Sayed said;

> This is by *design*. When having `“dd MMMM”`, `“d MMMM”`, `“MMMM dd”`, `“MMMM
>   d”` we use the genitive names. If you want to force using the
>   non-genitive name you can use `“ddd MMMM yyyy”`. By the way, this is the same 
>   behavior of Windows too when calling [`GetDateFormatEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can check which formats use genitive month names with `IsUseGenitiveForm` method on [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr).

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/67a86c9e114593ce1d24ef7b8a943b86438c0e46/src/mscorlib/src/System/Globalization/DateTimeFormat.cs#L372

Also they said;

> It is by design because the combination of `d`, `dd` with `MMMM`
>   *always* uses the genitive month names. Using `ddd` will produce the day of week. If someone really want avoid using the genitive month
>   names, they can either:
>
> - Override the month names in `DateTimeFormatInfo` used for formatting
> - Format `“dd”` and then concatenate it with `“MMMM yyyy”`

Comment: I've found that one, but then I've to set it everytime I need to use this OR everywhere in the whole project the genitive names won't be used....