# Medium month text format change

Tags: c#

I'm not sure exactly when, but at some point Microsoft has changed the text format for medium length month (`MMM`) to result in the same abbreviated month name, but ending in a '.' character.

Old style (.NET Framework 4.0 - ???):

```
new DateTime(2023, 10, 1).ToString("MMM-d-yyyy") // Oct-1-2023
```

New style (??? - .NET 6):

```
new DateTime(2023, 10, 1).ToString("MMM-d-yyyy") // Oct.-1-2023
```

I've been ignoring this so far since it's almost a cosmetic-only change, but it isn't quite just cosmetic. I notice that this causes problems with older programs sharing data with newer programs, in cases where an old program needs to parse a new format string. Older programs throw an exception if they try to parse something like `"Oct.-1-2023"` (but not `"Oct-1-2023"`).

Is there a way to disable this and revert to the old-style format? I don't actually like the '.' character being there and would remove it in all cases if I could, not just because it can cause problems with parsing.

Comment: What is the exact operating system and what is the culture where you execute the code?

Comment: [No-repro](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bKWd8g).

Comment: @NineBerry I know. The question implies the change in formatting applies universally and only depends on the .NET version, which it does not, hence the counterexample.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69345101/why-does-datetime-now-tostringhh-tt-new-cultureinfode-return-differen

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795390/datetime-tostring-without-using-the-genitive-month-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 5 Microsoft [has internally switched](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) from using the NLS libraries for culture support to using the ICU libraries. Different from NLS, ICU obeys that some cultures make a difference between normal month names and genitive month names. In these cultures, the placeholder MMM will be replaced with the abbreviated genitive month name. For example in cultures like Canadian English, Netherlands or German, this results in a dot being added after the abbreviated month name. There may be even other forms of modifications in other cultures.

### Approaches for solving the issue:

---

You can force your application to use NLS again instead of ICU. For that, add the following to your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

(Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69345224/101087)

Note that this only works on Windows and might not work any longer in some future version of .NET.

---

If the formatted string is not meant for the user but for internal storage, specifically use `Culture.InvariantCulture` to create a completely culture-independent string representation of your date.

```
string s = new DateTime(2023, 10, 1).ToString("MMM-d-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

Explicitly modify the culture information in your process so that the genitive version of the abbreviated month names is the same as the normal version.

```
// Get copy of current culture
var modifiedCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

// Override genetive abbreviated month names with normale abbreviated month names
modifiedCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = modifiedCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames;

// Set as default
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = modifiedCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = modifiedCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = modifiedCulture;
```

---

Create a modified version of the current culture where the genitive version of the abbreviated month names is the same as the normal version. And use it explicitely.

```
// Get copy of current culture
var modifiedCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

// Override genetive abbreviated month names with normale abbreviated month names
modifiedCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = modifiedCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames;

// Use modified culture explicitely
string s = new DateTime(2023, 10, 1).ToString("MMM-d-yyyy", modifiedCulture);
```

---

Format the month part separate from the rest. This way, the genetive version of the month name isn't used:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2023, 10, 1);
string s = dt.ToString("MMM") + dt.ToString("-d-yyyy");
```