# Trouble with AbbreviatedMonthNames

Tags: c#, date, .net-7.0, culture

It seems that the masses have spoken and basically the shorthand for September is now Sept.

So whilst [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)
Works on the principle (which my datepicker uses) my operating system has not got the memo (at present) and continues to work with Sep.

Anyway, so in an attempt to resolve this I've added in

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;
dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames  = new  string[] {
                "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", ""
            };
dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthNames;

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = ci;
```

Into my program file and this does seem to have resolve the issue and - I'm hoping that when Windows 11 comes around (for me) I might not need that code.

The question I have is - is this the right solution?
My application is only going to be used in the Uk, but I'm a little wary. I seem to have created a new culture and basically forced the program to use it.

Is this the right approach?

--

Edit, sorry I'll backup slightly - so when it comes to datepickers I like to use the format `dd-MMM-yyyy`. It's pretty standard where users/staff can come from all parts and just removes any "ambiguity" over date formats. Uk vs US for instance.

---

As for official "The masses have spoken" - TBH I might have spoken out of turn. However
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat
https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/b0a6207ff224a6cd8ca7f888c8a4740bacb83124/common/main/en_GB.xml#L1977
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/87307

There seems to be a few discussions about it ..
And someone, somewhere did make the call...

--

Just for further clarity I'm using the Tempus Dominus datepicker.
https://getdatepicker.com/
Which is using the Intl.DateTimeFormat methods.

Comment: First of all, not sure why you would care about what this is anyway. If you are sending stuff from JS to C#, then you should be using a proper format meant for transmitting over the wire. (e.g. ISO8601) Secondly, instead of creating a new culture, you may want to create it based on the existing one, e.g. `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone()`

Comment: What's the actual problem? The standards haven't changed, and the date pickers return either ISO8601 values or `Date` objects, not localized abbreviations.

Comment: *"It seems that the masses have spoken and basically the shorthand for September is now Sept."* [citation needed] (No, seriously, if some official standard regarding that changed, I'd love to know more details.)

Comment: As [MDN shows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value) the `value` attribute of both `input type='date'` and `input type='datetime-local'` is always ISO8601, even though the display text changes to match the browser's locale. This makes it really hard to understand what this question asks. Are you trying to format a date for display perhaps? .NET Core uses the [ICU library for globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu), not Windows, to ensure the same behavior on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Medium month text format change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77212314/medium-month-text-format-change)

Comment: The clone thing from DavidG answers it and I'm a bit happier with the Clone than new.

Comment: @RichardHousham `I like to use the format` you haven't explained what you mean by DatePicker yet. `Value` is always YYYY-MM-DD. The display format depends on the end user's browser settings but various components also allow changing the display format

Comment: Agreed, it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve by replacing Sep with Sept. As month name abbreviations, they both unambiguously refer to September.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt", new CultureInfo("de"))" return different results in different versions of .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69345101/why-does-datetime-now-tostringhh-tt-new-cultureinfode-return-differen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think some of this depends on your operating system and choice of datapicker.
For me using https://getdatepicker.com/ and on windows 10. The right way to fix this is

1. Install the Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime via nuget
2. Create the file runtimeconfig.template.json in the root of the project

add in the content

```
{
      "configProperties": {
        "System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu": "72"
      }
    }
```

When you compile this it then goes into the runtimeconfig.json in the bin file. But that file can get overwritten (and probably is't source controlled if you are using such things.

And your done. On the whole this is probably the best method espicially if you are using that datepicker and developing an application that could be used in various conntries. (and also using the short month format ; - "MMM")

Comment: Note, works in ASP.Core as well.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell whether this is the right solution, it depends on the purpose for which you must use Sept. Now .net uses the [ICU library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) to achieve globalization. ICU changed the abbreviation for September from Sep to Sept in version 68 ([CLDR-38](https://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-38)). The latest version on Windows 11 should be 68 (you can find icu.dll in the system32 folder), So if you try updating the system, you should be able to see the Sept.

If you want to use a specific ICU version, you can compile or [download](https://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/deps/vs16/x64/) the ICU dlls, put them in the root directory of the program, and then add the following lines to the `.runtimeconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu": "72"
    }
  }
}
```

This change will affect the behavior of `Parse` and `ParseExact`, with the majority of English cultures being affected, but `en` and `en-US` cultures still insist on using Sep.

Comment: I tried to add that in appsettings.json (the only json I have but no luck)

Comment: It should be in the output folder with the exe file, if you don't see it, just create one with the name `<ProgramName>.runtimeconfig.json`

Comment: Thanks but that can get overwritten - best bet is to create runtimeconfig.template.json and add the config properties in there. Seems to be way...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/

Comment: Yikes... this sounds like a breaking change for some applications, where downstream code may be looking for exact abbreviations. But at least this might also explain why MS/.Net is seemingly behind "the masses" on this, as MS has long had a very careful approach to introducing breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks to everyone - it's been a roller coaster. Appriciate all the comments and help.