Why is the month abbreviated differently when the date format includes a slot for days as opposed to when it doesn’t?
When running a .NET 8 console application, why does MMM show "June" instead of "Jun" when its part of a date format (e.g. .ToString("dd-MMM-yy")) but "Jun" (e.g., .ToString("MMM")) when its by itself?
// Set culture to English (Australia)
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");

// Get the current date
var currentDate = new DateTime(2024, 6, 8);

// Display the current date using the short date pattern
var formattedDate = currentDate.ToString("d", culture);
Console.WriteLine("Short date in en-AU culture: " + formattedDate); // Outputs: 8/06/2024

// Display the abbreviated month name separately
var abbreviatedMonth = currentDate.ToString("MMM", culture);
Console.WriteLine("Abbreviated month: " + abbreviatedMonth); // Outputs: Jun

var incorrect = currentDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy", culture);
Console.WriteLine("Incorrect format: " + incorrect); // Outputs: 08-June-24

Windows gets it right, but not C#. Note the month in the bottom right of the screenshot (I changed my Windows time to be in the month of June).


Seems like another quirk of using the ICU for localisation. Does it work as expected if you use NLS?

https://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/en_AU/Gregorian/17b01857bac73ef2 sheds some light on this – apparently the abbreviated with in en_AU is indeed June, etc.

@AKX Yeah, I was about to say that. This doesn't explain the output of .ToString("MMM", culture)  though. Presumably in this case it would use the standalone form, but the standalone form is the same for en_AU.

Another fun fact: "MMM-yy" evaluates to Jun-24 but "dd-MMM" to 08-June. Whenever the format string contains the day part MMM evaluates to June otherwise to Jun. Could that be used as an indicator for complex format strings if it contains the day part somewhere? ;o)

I have now seen the below Github article on something along the same lines but my issue is more the inconsistency between "MMM" and "dd-MMM-yy". https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/86643

@Adam, "the bottom right of the screenshot" shows 08-Jun-24. Was it meant to illustrate the issue?

@Astrogator That's proving his comment that "Windows  gets it right., but not C#" The screenshot is the Windows clock, which is showing it as he expects, but his app is not.

@Elezar, hm, tricky 'cause Win-clock sits in the taskbar, which is usually at the bottom of the screen, but the shown dialog goes further down! Yes, you can move the taskbar, but it stays attached to the border, doesn't it? So is the image doctored, or of smth else? My point: there's no June in the image anywhere.. And Win10/11 Notifications are constantly ignoring my yyyy-MMM-dd custom setting, always using mm/dd/yy format, so I'd not say "Windows gets it right" (yes, bending the original Q, but still related).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/35795390/333014

There are two abbreviations for months in DateTimeFormatInfo, one is called AbbreviatedMonthNames and the other is called AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames. The abbreviation of June in AbbreviatedMonthNames is Jun and in AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames it is June.
The explanation of genitive month names in the document is as follows:

In some languages, a month name that is part of a date appears in the genitive case. For example, a date in the ru-RU or Russian (Russia) culture consists of the day number and the genitive month name, such as 1 Января (1 January).

The key code for which abbreviation to choose is here: IsUseGenitiveForm, and its comment says:

Action: Check the format to see if we should use genitive month in the formatting. Starting at the position (index) in the (format) string, look back and look ahead to see if there is "d" or "dd".  In the case like "d MMMM" or "MMMM dd", we can use genitive form.  Genitive form is not used if there is more than two "d".

So if there is d or dd in the format, June will be chosen.

I guess the problem is not caused by the genetive form logic. Instead, it seems to be caused by a wrong default initialization of the AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames property in newer versions of .NET. (I don't believe that the en-AU culture would actually define such different genitive abbreviations for the months. But if I am mistaken I would be very happy to learn more about it. I tried to check the AS/NZS ISO 8601.1:2021 standard, but its price of about $160 AUD is holding me back.)

As shingo already pointed out, the behavior seems to originate in the logic that use the properties DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames and DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames.
However, a solution to the problem has not yet been offered.
Those two properties have public setters. It might be quite easy to manipulate those arrays so that they have the expected contents.
// Set culture to English (Australia)
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");

// Workaround for unexpected month abbreviations:
culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames =
    new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
                   "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                   "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
                   "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
                   "" };

// Get the current date
var currentDate = new DateTime(2024, 6, 8);

// Display the current date using the short date pattern
var formattedDate = currentDate.ToString("d", culture);
Console.WriteLine("Short date in en-AU culture: " + formattedDate); // Outputs: 8/06/2024

// Display the abbreviated month name separately
var abbreviatedMonth = currentDate.ToString("MMM", culture);
Console.WriteLine("Abbreviated month: " + abbreviatedMonth); // Outputs: Jun

var fixedIncorrect = currentDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy", culture);
Console.WriteLine("Fixed incorrect format: " + fixedIncorrect); // Outputs: 08-Jun-24  :-)

It is unclear to me why certain versions of .NET expose different values for these month abbreviations for the en-AU culture. In .NET Framework 4.7.2, it works fine by default. So there does seem to be something wrong in the newer versions of .NET, since Australian date/time formatting policy itself does not change overnight.

Wouldn't you rather just assign culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames;?

Or even better, could you just unset the UseGenitiveMonth flag in the date time format info flags?

@Bergi Your first suggestion would work very well. But the second suggestion needs some clarification. I browsed through the documented properties of DateTimeFormatInfo but failed to find a flag named UseGenitiveMonth. A direct search using my favorite browser yielded no results either. Can you please provide some more information about that flag?

Oh it's private DateTimeFormatFlags formatFlags, my bad :-/ I found them in the code shingo had linked, I don't write any C#... They get initialised by the internal DateTimeFormatInfoScanner.GetFormatFlagGenitiveMonth it seems.
